# Linux containers: command to temporarily block local port?

Tags: docker, firewall, iptables

From within a container, I'm trying to temporarily block access to a port in the same network. For example:

```
services:
  cli:
    image: node:latest-alpine

  redis:
    image: redis:latest-alpine
```

Inside `cli`, I want to temporarily block `localhost:6379` (redis). I have tried the following:

```
iptables-legacy -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j DROP
do something
iptables-legacy -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
```

But it does not work, I keep getting "operation not permitted". Any other options other than iptables?

Comment: Questions about finding the right UNIX command for a system administration purpose are generally better fit to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: BTW, "operation not permitted" in a Docker container, assuming you're root, generally means you're in a container that was configured to be restricted in which syscalls into the kernel you can access. It's possible to tell Docker to privilege a container and give it full access, though that's not ideal if you're worried about an attacker who broke into a service running inside it trying to escape to the host.

Comment: Have you considered, instead of temporarily changing the rules at runtime, having a more complex rule and changing the environment to control whether that rule matches? Say, one that blocks only traffic inside a current cgroup or from a specific user; then you can run your test (or whatever) that's not supposed to be able to communicate on that port inside that cgroup / as that user / etc.

Comment: Hi Charles! Thanks for your insight. I think it helps to provide the context of this scenario: this is a development Docker setup that I want to use for load testing, as well as fault tolerance, making sure the system can work with certain external connections blocked.

Comment: The system is a bit legacy so adding a proper test layer on the application itself would be difficult, thus the "hardcore" approach of blocking connection on the network layer.

Comment: Gotcha. There _are_ other layers you can do that at before the firewall gets involved -- `LD_PRELOAD` shims for injecting faults are a thing, f/e.

Comment: (I don't know if Docker unprivileged containers are permitted to set up eBPF syscall filters, but that's a thing too if so).